# SQL using same database item multiple times

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table:

```
Value | Win
 12      3
 22      4
 44      5
 12      11
```

At the moment getting `sum(Win)` and order by `Value`, it returns. So all winning by value.

```
Value | Win
 12      14
 22      4
 44      5
```

Now I don't want to just order by `Value`, I want to do it like this:

Return all winnings, where value is bigger than 10, 20, 30,40 :

So return should be:

```
Value | Win
 10+      23
 20+      9
 30+      5
 40+      5
```

Is this thing possible? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be advantages in a grouping table, for example:

[image: group table]

This will allow you to build:

[image: group table2]

Using:

```
SELECT Groups.GroupName, ta.Value
FROM Groups, ta
WHERE ta.Value Between [low] And [high]
```

Or even

```
WHERE ta.Value >= [low]
```

And finalize with:

```
SELECT GroupName, Count([Value]) , Sum(Win)
FROM (SELECT Groups.GroupName, ta.Value, ta.Win
FROM Groups, ta
WHERE ta.Value >= [low]) q
GROUP BY GroupName
```

One advantage is that you can add and remove groups very easily by editing the table.

Comment: Where are you summing the Win amount?

Comment: I have added the win above.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems I can only use the inner query also,  dont have to do select in select. The inner select gives me the needed result already. Am I doin smthin wrong?

Comment: Jaanus, are you sorted now or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT '10+' AS v,
SUM(IIF (myvalue>10, win)) AS w
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT '20+' AS v,
SUM(IIF (myvalue>20, win)) AS w
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT '30+' AS v,
SUM(IIF (myvalue>30, win)) AS w
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT '40+' AS v,
SUM(IIF (myvalue>40, win)) AS w
FROM mytable
```

**NOTE**: Field names I've used are slightly different from the names used in the question...

Answer (score 1):

In most databases, you would use a case statement:

```
select (case when value >= 40 then '40+'
             when value >= 30 then '30+'
             when value >= 20 then '20+'
             when value > 10 then '10+'
         end)
```

Unfortunetely, MS-Access does not support the case, so you have to use `iif` instead:

The easiest way is to put the expression in a subquery:

```
select valuegroup, sum(win)
from (select t.*,
             iif(value > 40, '40+',
                 iif(value > 30, '30+',
                     iif(value > 20, '20+',
                         iif(value > 10, '10+', '<10'
                 )))) as valuegroup
      from t
     ) t
group by valuegroup
```

To get a running sum, you need to do a self join.  Silly, but Access doesn't have window functions:

```
select valuegroup, sum(cumwin)
from (select t.*, sum(t2.win) as cumwin,
             iif(t.value > 40, '40+',
                 iift.(value > 30, '30+',
                     iif(t.value > 20, '20+',
                         iif(t.value > 10, '10+', '<10'
                 )))) as valuegroup
      from t join
           t t2
           on t.value <= t2.value
      group by t.value
     ) t
group by valuegroup
```

If MS Access doesn't let you put `valuegroup` in the `group by` of the outer query, then you have to put in the whole expression.

Comment: Does the 10+ add all the values from 20+,30+ and 40+ ?

Comment: I'm sorry.  I misread the question.  You want cumulative sums.

Comment: Yes and I believe you cant group by `as` variable. Thanks for effort though. This is almost what I need :)